# Angular console.log in tests printing in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Jasmine/Karma for unit testing my Angular application, and I'm using Visual Studio Code as the IDE.

When I do `console.log` in the test, I'm not able to find where the output is printed.

My test code is:

```
it('verify filter changes', () => {

    let nameInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name-input'));
    console.log(nameInput);
    nameInput.nativeElement.value = 'dummyName';
    nameInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.name).toBe('dummyName');
  });
```

My karma.conf.json:

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: true,
      },
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      captureConsole: true,
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    //browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    browserConsoleLogOptions: {
      level: 'log',
      format: '%b %T: %m',
      terminal: true
    }
  });
};
```

Where is the output of console.log printed in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47#issuecomment-54759048

Comment: @JoelJoseph I've updated the question with my karma.conf.json. I tried the solution in the github link, but it isn't working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try observing `Output` (View > Output) and selecting appropriate item from the dropdown?

Comment: @31piy I tried various options in that dropdown. I'm not seeing anything from my console.log

Comment: I can see the output in `DEBUG CONSOLE`

Comment: Someone else or yourself may have explicitly disabled logging in the unit test. This could have been done with `spyOn(console, 'log').and.callFake(m => null);` or similar statement inside `beforeEach` for example.